# c# Use double but only with 2 decimals with NUnit Tests for Mathematical operations

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nunit

Im currently writing a program where i am calculating Areas and Perimeters of basic geometric objects (Square, Rectangle, Circle, Triangle). And to check that these operations are correct i am using NUnit to test the methods.

I am using Double for these operations, and my problem is that i dont want so many decimals to be the correct expected Value to pass a NUnit test.

Lets say i have a circle that has a radius with 5, to get this Area we do

```
5 * 5 * Math.Pi = 78.539816339744831d
```

This is what i have to Assert to make the test pass, but is there any way to limit so i can only work with 1 decimal? So that i should be able to make the test pass with value 78.5 instead of 78.539816339744831d

Thank you!

Comment: If the AUT is written to use `double` then your unit tests should be using more than 1 digit to the right of the decimal point otherwise your tests could be considered meaningless.  If however the AUT doesn't care so much for precision it might benefit from being re-written to use `float`s

Comment: What do you mean by AUT?

Comment: **AUT:** _application under test_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify rounding range in your `Assert` this way `Is.EqualTo(78.5).Within(0.1)`.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit has an overload to `Assert.AreEqual` that takes a third argument, the delta.

You can do:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, 0.1);
```

to assert that "actual" is within 0.1 of "expected".

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.Round (with '1' being the amount of decimals)

```
double result = Math.Round(this.GetFieldValue("value"), 1);
```